# Passing variables aquired using flask as input to script

Tags: python, flask

I have a python setup where one method continuously returns the IDs of scanned RFID chips. Now I cut the cord and have the scanner hooked up to a wifi microcontroller (ESP8266). Every time a chip is scanned a GET request is issued containing the chip's ID.

I put the flask part in a simple script. I don't need anything returned to the ESP8266. I would like to just have a class or functions that just return the collected value. I can print the value to stdout where it appears also with flask's log output but this doesn't really help. How do I pass `uid` to a different script, what am I missing?

The script in question:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/urlpath/<uid>')
def rfiduid(uid):
    print uid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to import your other and call it directly from within the route.

```
from flask import Flask

# A module which contains the stuff you're trying to do
from myothermodule import processRFID

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/urlpath/<uid>')
def rfiduid(uid):
    # Pass the UID to your other module here
    processRFID(uid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```

If your other code is *literally* a script (that accepts input arguments from the command line) I would recommend modifying it so that it contains a function that you can call from the flask app. Otherwise, you will need to use an `os.system` call or something to execute the other script with arguments. This is **highly discouraged** since you are passing un-sanitized user input (via the url) to your system.

```
@app.route('/urlpath/<uid>')
def rfiduid(uid):
    os.system(' '.join(['script.py', uid]))
```

This could be exploited if a UID were passed as `'1 && really_bad_system_command'`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. 

I thought of this as well, making the flask part a part of my master script. So far I had frontend processes, backend communication, and GUI separated in different modules. It is actually more of an application than a script.

Comment: @PiEnthusiast I'm not recommending making it *part* of the flask app. You can keep it in it's own `*.py` file but just import it at the beginning and use it from there. That keeps things both modular and functional